# Ubuntuのアクティビティメニューでスクロールすると表示が乱れる

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, gnome

Ubuntu 19.10でアプリケーションの一覧を開きスクロールすると下記画像のようになります。
UbuntuはWindows10をHostとするVirtualbox上で動いています。

アプリケーションの一覧を閉じると通常通りにデスクトップに戻ります。
また、**このアプリケーションの一覧の画面以外で(例えばブラウザなど)スクロールしてもこの症状は発生しません**
さらに、Windows上でもこの症状は**発生しません**。

また、HostマシンはCore i7-6700(4C8T) でRAMは16GBでGuestは4CoreでRAMは10GBなので性能不足ということでもないと思います

どのようにすれば直すことができるのでしょうか?

[image: 乱れた画面]

Comment: Guest Additonsはインストールされていますか？また、3Dアクセラレーションは有効化されていますか？画面周りの問題ですので、グラフィック関係をチェックした方がいいと思います。

Comment: はい、両方ともインストールされています

Comment: 直接の回答ではありませんが、もし可能ならばvmware Workstation playerでも同じ現象になるか試してみてください。https://www.vmware.com/jp/products/workstation-player.html